# link list segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, singly-linked-list

```
typedef struct node{
int data;
struct node *link;
}nd;

nd *head=NULL , *ahead=NULL;

void create_node(int item) {
    nd *new, *temp;
    new = (nd*)malloc(sizeof(nd));
    new->data=item;
    new->link=NULL;
    if(head==NULL) {
        head=new;
    }
    else {
        temp=head;
        while(temp->link!=NULL) {
            temp=temp->link;
        }
        temp->link=new;
    }

}

void alpha_check(int size) {
    int i,j,num;
    nd *ti , *tj;
    ti=tj=head;
    for(i=1 ; i<=size ; i++) {
        for(j=1 ; j<=size ; j++) {
            num = ((ti->data)*10)+(tj->data);
            tj=tj->link;

            /*if(num>=65 && num<=90) {
                   printf("\n->%d",num);
              }*/
        }
     //ti=ti->link;
    }
}

void traverse(nd *thead) {
    while(thead->link!=NULL) {
        printf("%d ",thead->data);
        thead=thead->link;
    }
    printf("%d ",thead->data); 
}
```

So the only problem in the above code lies in the function **alpha_check()** where i want the variable **tj** point to the next node. Instead of pointing to the next node its giving me **Segmentation fault (core dumped)**.
please explain why can't I make tj point to the next node.

Comment: for(i=1 ; i<=size ; i++)
{
     for(j=1 ; j<=size ; j++)
     { .   is a problem ..you need to add a flag to traverse until thread->link !=NULL

Comment: We don't see how the list is created, nor how `alpha_check` is called. It seems this `size` is wrong. It is also strange to traverse a list using a size and not a while loop until end-of-list. Use a debugger. It will tell you what is wrong and where it happens.

Comment: What is the size that you are passing to function alpha_check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segmentation fault is a signal to the kernel that your program is accessing memory that it doesn't have have permission to causing the kernel to terminate your program.  This usually means you are exceeding the bounds of an array or in your case you are dereferencing a pointer that is pointing to something it shouldn't be.  Like the others alluded to in their comments you need to have a different type of constraint while traversing a linked list than you would when traversing an array.  You need to traverse while checking that the node pointer is not NULL rather than doing some fixed size in a for loop.

I've made a change to your alpha_check procedure and added a main for testing it.  It works as you would expect.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* link;
} nd;

nd *head=NULL , *ahead=NULL;

void create_node(int item) {
    nd* new,* temp;
    new = (nd*)malloc(sizeof(nd));
    new->data = item;
    new->link = NULL;

    printf("%d %p\n", new->data, new);

    if(head == NULL) {
        head = new;
    }
    else {
        temp = head;
        while(temp->link)
            temp = temp->link;
        temp->link = new;

    }
}

void alpha_check(int size) {
    int i,j,num;
    nd* ti ,* tj;
    ti = tj = head;

    for(i = 1 ; i <= size ; i++) {
        while(tj) {
            num = ti->data * 10 + tj->data;
            tj = tj->link;

         //if(num>=65 && num<=90)
         //{
            printf("\n->%d",num);
            printf(" %p\n", tj);
         //}
     }
     //ti=ti->link;
    }
}

void traverse(nd* thead) {
    while(thead->link) {
        printf("%d ", thead->data);
        thead = thead->link;
    }
    printf("%d ", thead->data);
}

int main(void) {
    create_node(10);
    create_node(1);
    create_node(5);

    alpha_check(2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use a for loop with a size if you create a structure that contains the head pointer and some variable that tracks the size of the list.
`struct List {
    size_t size;
    nd* head;
}`

You can also use a for loop instead of a while loop to check the pointer is no null `for(tj = head; tj; tj = tj->link)`